# Postfix/spamassassin not delivering to alias when specifying user executing spamc

Tags: postfix, spamassassin

I have installed SpamAssassin and configured it to read preferences from sql. I realised that it wasn't reading the user's preferences, and checking the logs I saw that all requests sent by the `spamc` client were executed as the spamd user.

Here it is how the spamc client is executed as configured in the `master.cf` file (Postfix):

```
spamassassin unix -     n       n       -       -       pipe
        user=spamd argv=/usr/bin/spamc  -f -e
        /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}
```

I added `-u ${recipient}` to spamc, and saw in the logs that it worked, now the user's preferences are correctly fetched.

However, this sort of breaks my delivery to aliases.

Consider `alias@dom.org` being a postfix alias to `a@dom.org` and to `b@dom.org`. Adding the above `-u` to `spamc` leads to non-delivery of emails to the alias.

Here's a lot of postfix when it doesn't deliver the e-mail:

```
Feb 14 21:12:36 mail postfix/qmgr[51620]: 6EFD11003F5: from=<someone@another.no>, size=2588, nrcpt=2 (queue active)
Feb 14 21:12:37 mail postfix/pipe[51637]: 6EFD11003F5: to=<a@dom.org>, orig_to=<alias@dom.org>, relay=spamassassin, delay=1.3, delays=0.03/0/0/1.3, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via spamassassin service (X-Spam-Level:  X-Spam-Status: No, score=-1.9 required=3.0 tests=BAYES_00,SPF_HELO_PASS  autolearn=ha))
Feb 14 21:12:37 mail postfix/pipe[51637]: 6EFD11003F5: to=<b@dom.org>, orig_to=<alias@dom.org>, relay=spamassassin, delay=1.3, delays=0.03/0/0/1.3, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via spamassassin service (X-Spam-Level:  X-Spam-Status: No, score=-1.9 required=3.0 tests=BAYES_00,SPF_HELO_PASS  autolearn=ha))
Feb 14 21:12:37 mail postfix/qmgr[51620]: 6EFD11003F5: removed
```

I removed the `-u ${recipient}`, things work again, but I can't find much help from the following logs:

```
Feb 14 21:14:36 mail postfix/master[51877]: daemon started -- version 3.4.13, configuration /etc/postfix
Feb 14 21:15:26 mail postfix/qmgr[51880]: B9C531003F5: from=<someoneelse@another.no>, size=2580, nrcpt=2 (queue active)
Feb 14 21:15:27 mail postfix/pipe[51932]: B9C531003F5: to=<a@dom.org>, orig_to=<alias@dom.org>, relay=spamassassin, delay=1.2, delays=0.04/0.01/0/1.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via spamassassin service)
Feb 14 21:15:27 mail postfix/pipe[51932]: B9C531003F5: to=<b@dom.org>, orig_to=<alias@dom.org>, relay=spamassassin, delay=1.2, delays=0.04/0.01/0/1.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via spamassassin service)
Feb 14 21:15:27 mail postfix/qmgr[51880]: B9C531003F5: removed
Feb 14 21:15:27 mail postfix/qmgr[51880]: E19B7106C31: from=<someoneelse@another.no>, size=2969, nrcpt=2 (queue active)
Feb 14 21:15:28 mail postfix/qmgr[51880]: 01875106C30: from=<someoneelse@another.no>, size=3336, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

The spamassassin logs, when it doesn't work, are these:

```
Sun Feb 14 21:12:36 2021 [50514] info: spamd: processing message <1ec01535d2cb4106a8aa534ac9214126@another.no> for a@dom.org:5000
Sun Feb 14 21:12:36 2021 [50514] info: dns: no callback for id 21026/IN/A/bluetreehotels.com.br.dbl.spamhaus.org, ignored, packet on next debug line
Sun Feb 14 21:12:36 2021 [50514] info: dns: no likely matching queries for id 21026
Sun Feb 14 21:12:37 2021 [51696] info: util: setuid: ruid=5000 euid=5000 rgid=5000 5000 5000 egid=5000 5000 5000
Sun Feb 14 21:12:37 2021 [50514] info: spamd: clean message (-1.9/3.0) for a@dom.org:5000 in 1.3 seconds, 2502 bytes.
Sun Feb 14 21:12:37 2021 [50514] info: spamd: result: . -1 - BAYES_00,SPF_HELO_PASS scantime=1.3,size=2502,user=a@dom.org,uid=5000,required_score=3.0,rhost=127.0.0.1,raddr=127.0.0.1,rport=43164,mid=<1ec01535d2cb4106a8aa534ac9214126@another.no>,bayes=0.000000,autolearn=ham autolearn_force=no
Sun Feb 14 21:12:37 2021 [50512] info: prefork: child states: II
```

And when it works fine, are like these:

```
Sun Feb 14 21:15:26 2021 [50514] info: spamd: connection from 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1]:43402 to port 783, fd 5
Sun Feb 14 21:15:26 2021 [50514] info: spamd: processing message <c384026adcb64ae4813f888925e11bdd@another.no> for spamd:5000
Sun Feb 14 21:15:26 2021 [51934] info: util: setuid: ruid=5000 euid=5000 rgid=5000 5000 5000 egid=5000 5000 5000
Sun Feb 14 21:15:27 2021 [50514] info: spamd: clean message (-0.0/5.0) for spamd:5000 in 1.1 seconds, 2494 bytes.
Sun Feb 14 21:15:27 2021 [50514] info: spamd: result: . 0 - SPF_HELO_PASS scantime=1.1,size=2494,user=spamd,uid=5000,required_score=5.0,rhost=127.0.0.1,raddr=127.0.0.1,rport=43402,mid=<c384026adcb64ae4813f888925e11bdd@another.no>,autolearn=ham autolearn_force=no
```

Any clues on why this is happening? The clear difference here is that on the spamassassin log when it doesn't work, we see that `spamc` was called with the user `a@dom.org` (and not with `alias@dom.org` and not with `b@dom.org`). None of the recipients represented by the alias got the e-mail. On the second attempt, without the `-u` parameter, then spamc was executed without sending a user name (failing into the default `spamd` user), and the mails got delivered to the users `a` and `b`.

Could it be `sendmail`?

Best,

Francis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I fixed it.
Adding `spamassassin_destination_recipient_limit = 1` to `main.cf` (postfix) did the trick.